# Treating class as a constant

Tags: java, constants

```
abstract class Coin{
    String name;
    String currency;


    class EUR extends Coin{
        EUR() {
        super("EUR", "€");
        }

    }
    class USD extends Coin{
        USD() {
        super("USD", "$");
        }

    }

    private Coin (String name, String currency){
    this.name = name
    this.currency = currency}
    }

class Person{
    ///variables
    Coin coin;

    Person(//Variables, Coin coin){
        //Other assignments
        this.coin = coin
    }

}
```

Basically i would like to initialize a Person passing EUR as Coin, without creating a new EUR.
Something like

```
static final EUR euro = EUR
```

and then:

```
Person person = new Person(... , euro);
```

I do not need millions of instances of EUR so i don't want to create each time a new EUR

I know i can make something like this using constant Strings, but i actually want to pass a Coin object

I also tried initializing EUR inside Coin class like this

```
static EUR euro = new EUR();
```

But IDE is warning me this could cause thread deadlock

Comment: Try out enum instead of a class?

Comment: you need to use enum

Comment: or you can define `public static final Coin EUR = new Coin("EUR", "€");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect job for an enum:

```
public enum Coin {
    EUR("EUR", "€"),
    USD("USD", "$");

    private String name;
    private String currency;

    private Coin(String name, String currency) {
        this.name = name;
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

Once you've defined it, you can use the enum constants:

```
Person person = new Person(... , Coin.EUR);
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, if noone comes up with another one i will mark this as solution

Comment: @lugiank While probably there are other workarounds, this problem is specifically what `enum` was designer for. I am willing to bet that there will be no better solution / answer to this problem. Please consider accepting this one, so others can see that it indeed solve the problem elegantly